# Is it possible to use Bcrypt in a backbone app without requiring it in the js file?

Tags: backbone.js, gulp, require, browserify, bcrypt

in the bcrypt documentation, it says you have to require bcrypt, for example:

```
`var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
     bcrypt.hash('B4c0/\/', salt, function(err, hash) {
         //Store hash in your password DB.
     });
});`
```

I use gulp with my backbone app. If I require bcrypt like this in my javascript files, it takes gulp 12 seconds to run the scripts function because I also implement browserify. The bcrypt library has to be loaded in my app.js which takes a really long time.

So I thought I could require my Bcrypt in a script tag in my Index.html, but then I can't access the Bcrypt functions like bcrypt.hash, bcrypt.hashSync, ...

Is there a way to use bcrypt without the var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the [node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) version ;)